# how to combine two objects in angularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have two requests, one getting the employee info and the other getting the Allowance info. The two are related by the `empID`. How can I combine these two requests in angularJS as show in Level 3?

Level 1 : this is the employee information

```
[
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "fullName": "Lamin   L  Janneh",
    "Job": "Software Developer",
    "Dept": "Tech",
    "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
    "Account": "789653214",
    "tin": "785421369"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "fullName": "Agie   A  Fatou",
    "Job": "Software Developer",
    "Dept": "Tech",
    "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
    "Account": "8521479",
    "tin": "7895214"
  }
]
```

Level 2: this is the employee Allowance information object

```
[
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "700.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "700.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "name": "Credit Allowance",
    "amount": "1000.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "450.00"
  }
]
```

Level 2: how can I combine these two objects?

```
[
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "fullName": "Lamin   L  Janneh",
    "Job": "Software Developer",
    "Dept": "Tech",
    "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
    "Account": "789653214",
    "tin": "785421369",
    "Allowance":[
        {
            "empID": "PC145",
            "name": "Credit Allowance",
            "amount": "1000.00"
        },{
        "empID": "PC145",
        "name": "Credit Allowance",
        "amount": "1000.00"
      }]
    },
    {
        "empID": "PC676",
        "fullName": "Agie   A  Fatou",
        "Job": "Software Developer",
        "Dept": "Tech",
        "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
        "Account": "8521479",
        "tin": "7895214",
        "Allowance" : 
            [{
                "empID": "PC676",
                "name": "House Allowance",
                "amount": "700.00"
              },
              {
                "empID": "PC676",
                "name": "House Allowance",
                "amount": "700.00"
             }]
 }
]
```

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This isn't a code writing or a tutorial service. You will get lots of help when you show the code that isn't working however

Comment: these are the two request on angularJS
 $http.get('/api/PreviewEmployee').success(function (data)
    {
        $scope.employee = data;
    });

and
 $http.get('/api/PreviewAllowance').success(function (data) {
        $scope.Allowance = data;
    });

please I am new in angularJS

Comment: FYI what you have are objects - nothing to do with JSON at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var master = [
```

{
      "empID": "PC145",
      "fullName": "Lamin   L  Janneh",
      "Job": "Software Developer",
      "Dept": "Tech",
      "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
      "Account": "789653214",
      "tin": "785421369"
  },
  {
      "empID": "PC676",
      "fullName": "Agie   A  Fatou",
      "Job": "Software Developer",
      "Dept": "Tech",
      "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
      "Account": "8521479",
      "tin": "7895214"
  }
    ];

```
var detail =  [
```

{
      "empID": "PC676",
      "name": "House Allowance",
      "amount": "700.00"
  },
  {
      "empID": "PC676",
      "name": "House Allowance",
      "amount": "700.00"
  },
  {
      "empID": "PC145",
      "name": "Credit Allowance",
      "amount": "1000.00"
  },
  {
      "empID": "PC145",
      "name": "House Allowance",
      "amount": "450.00"
  }
    ];

```
for (var inxMaster = 0; inxMaster < master.length; inxMaster++)
{
   master[inxMaster].Allowance = [];
    for (var inxDetail = 0; inxDetail < detail.length; inxDetail++) {
        if (master[inxMaster].empID === detail[inxDetail].empID)
        {
            master[inxMaster].Allowance.push(detail[inxDetail]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to only do this when you have received ***both*** sets of data, so make sure to place the call to the following function at the right place:

```js
function mergeAllowances(employee, allowance) {
    // 1. create map for level 1 and add allowance property

    var dict = employee.reduce(function (dict, emp) {
        emp.allowance = [];
        dict[emp.empID] = emp;
        return dict;
    }, {});


    // 2. Populate allowance property

    allowance.forEach(function (entry) {
        dict[entry.empID].allowance.push(entry);
    });

    return employee;
}

// Sample data. Instead you would use $scope.employeee and $scope.Allowance
var employee = [
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "fullName": "Lamin   L  Janneh",
    "Job": "Software Developer",
    "Dept": "Tech",
    "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
    "Account": "789653214",
    "tin": "785421369"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "fullName": "Agie   A  Fatou",
    "Job": "Software Developer",
    "Dept": "Tech",
    "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
    "Account": "8521479",
    "tin": "7895214"
  }
];

var allowance = [
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "700.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "700.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "name": "Credit Allowance",
    "amount": "1000.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "450.00"
  }
];

// Apply merge to employee
mergeAllowances(employee, allowance);
// Output result
console.log(employee);
```

Note that I would not write `Allowance` with a capital: use camelCase instead, so `allowance`. Initial capitals are usually used for classes/constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

where

```
var parent= [
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "fullName": "Lamin   L  Janneh",
    "Job": "Software Developer",
    "Dept": "Tech",
    "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
    "Account": "789653214",
    "tin": "785421369"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "fullName": "Agie   A  Fatou",
    "Job": "Software Developer",
    "Dept": "Tech",
    "bank": "Trust Bank Limited",
    "Account": "8521479",
    "tin": "7895214"
  }
];

var child= [
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "700.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC676",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "700.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "name": "Credit Allowance",
    "amount": "1000.00"
  },
  {
    "empID": "PC145",
    "name": "House Allowance",
    "amount": "450.00"
  }
];
```

Your function can be looks like this

```
for (i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) 
{ 
    parent[i].Allowance = [];  
    for(var j = 0; j< child.length; j++) { 
        if(parent[i].empID == child[j].empID) {
        parent[i].Allowance.push(child[j])
       }
    }   
}
```